# Unable to understand requirement of passport.initialize() middleware

Tags: express, authentication, oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-oauth

I have defined a route 'auth/google' which is responsible for logging into app with google.Consent Screen appears for signin(no passport.initialize() required).I have defined callback Url as 'auth/google/callback' too. Why am I getting error middleware(passport.initialize() ) not in use

```
// using pasport.authenticate for authenicate the request (no error for  not using passport.initialize())

app.get('/auth/google' , passport.authenticate('google',{
scope: ['profile','email'] 
}) 

// got error after writing below code

app.get('/auth/google/callback' , passport.authenticate('google'),(req,res)=>{
 res.json({"a":97});
});
```

Comment: can you post your middleware import order?

Comment: I have a route file 'authroutes.js' which has both routes & exported a function to require it in index.js(entry file) & i have configured google Strategy in passport.js file . In Entry File I have commented the initialization of passport due to which i am getting error

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal passport.serializeuser() is not invoking without passport.initialize().Why is it?

Comment: checkout the answer posted

Answer (score 0):

In a Connect or Express-based application, passport.initialize() middleware is required to initialize Passport. If your application uses persistent login sessions, passport.session() middleware must also be used.

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.static('public'));
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

`passport.initialize(`) is a middle-ware that initialises Passport.

**Middlewares** are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle.

Passport is an authentication middleware for Node that authenticates requests.

> So basically, `passport.initialize()` initialises the authentication
>   module

.

If you read the [passport.js docs configure section](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/) you'll know the intialization is the first step to register you authentication module.

Also, to comment over the flow of Passport authentication module

There are three main parts in using passport.js:

1. Requiring the module and using its passport.initialize() and
   passport.session() middleware with express.
2. Configuring passport
       with at least one Strategy and setting up passport's serializeUser
       and deserializeUser methods.
3. Specifying a route which uses the
       passport.authenticate middleware to actually authenticate a user.

Comment: If we have to use session in our app then passport should serialize a user for which this middleware is required. I have understand this by reading this [https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/initialize.js] **Correct me if I am wrong** What are the other ways for session maintain?

Comment: yes , you're correct passport.session() can and cannot be used but since its an authentication library its better to manage the session using this middleware , also passport has the capability to sync the session while using Session strategy .But in your specific case i didn't get why did you avoid `passport.initialize() `

Comment: Other ways to maintain session would be using `express-session` which is a middleware for storing and maintaining session in an express routed application